# Flatten monad stack

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, lifting

So I have this sort of code all over my first serious haskell project:

```
f :: (MonadTrans t) => ExceptT () (t (StateT A B)) C
f = do mapExceptT lift $ do
    lift $ do
        ...
        lift $ do
            ...
            r <- ...
            ...
            return r
    >>= \r -> ...
```

There definitely may be something wrong about how I try to achieve my goals (there might be simpler ways how to do it) but currently I am interested in learning how to handle a stack of monad transformers in some nicer way, if there is one. This is the only way I figured out how to get `r` in the context of `B` and lift it to a monad higher in the stack. Lifting whole blocks instead of initial statements is as far as I could get on my own.

What I also often end up with are chains of `lift` which I found out can be avoided with `liftIO` if the deep monad is `IO`. I am not aware of a generic way for other monads though.

Is there a pattern that one can follow when he ends up dealing with such stacks, and having to extract one value at some level, a different value at a different level, combine these and affect any of the two levels or maybe yet another one?

Can the stack be manipulated somehow without neither lifting whole blocks (which causes `let` and bound variables to be scoped and restricted to the inner block) nor having to `lift . lift . ... lift` individual actions?

Comment: See the [What I Wish I Knew When Learning Haskell section on Newtype Deriving](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#newtype-deriving), it gives some example code for flattening a transformer stack.

Comment: And see also [this newer SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572152/tidying-up-monads-turning-application-of-a-monad-transformer-into-newtype-mona)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a well-known problem with monad transformers in general. Researchers have devised various ways of handling it, none of which is clearly "best". Some of the known solutions include:

- The [`mtl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) approach, which automatically lifts type classes of monads over its built-in monad transformers (and *only* its built-in monad transformers). This allows you to just write `f :: (MonadState A m, MonadError () m) => m C` if those are the only features of the monad that your function is using. Due to its extreme non-portability and a few other reasons, `mtl` is generally considered pseudo-deprecated. See [this page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_Transformer_Library) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769487/mtl-transformers-monads-fd-monadlib-and-the-paradox-of-choice) for the gory details.
- If you have a *particular* monad stack you are using over and over again, you can wrap it in a `newtype` and write instances of the various monad type classes it supports manually. For `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad`, and any other type classes implemented by the top-level transformer in your stack, you can use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to have the compiler write the instances for you automatically; for other type classes, you will have to insert the appropriate number of `lift` calls for each method. The advantage of this approach is that it's more general and simpler to understand while giving you the same flexibility at the call site as `mtl`. The big problem with this approach is that it encourages using a single "mega-monad" for all operations rather than specifying only the needed operations, since adding any new monad transformer to the stack requires writing a whole new list of instances.
- In most cases, you don't really want a monad that has "some arbitrary state of type `A`" and "some arbitrary exception-throwing capability". Rather, the different features offered by your monad stack have some semantic meaning in your mental model of your program. A variation of the previous approach is to create custom type classes for the effects beyond the basic `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` and write instances for the custom type classes on your `newtype`'d monad instead. This has a major advantage over the other approaches listed here: you can have a stack with multiple copies of the same monad transformer in it at different positions. This is the strategy I've used the most in my own programs so far.
- A completely different approach is *effect systems*. Normally, an effect system has to be built in to a language's type system, but it's possible to [encode an effect system in Haskell's type system](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~dorchard/publ/haskell14-effects.pdf). See the [effect-monads](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/effect-monad) package.

Comment: I gather that effect systems have their own serious limitations.

Comment: The problem is that I do not really have too many occurrences of the exact same stack. It's just that I often have some stacks and plenty of lifting therefore.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm sure they do. I don't have any first-hand experience with effect systems though so I can't speak to that.

Answer (score 4):

The usual approach is to use the `mtl` library rather than using `transformers` directly. I'm not sure what the story behind your `t` is, but the usual `mtl` approach is to use very general type signatures at definition sites, like

```
foo :: (MonadError e m, MonadState s m) => m Int
```

Then fix the actual transformer stacks at the call sites. A common recommendation is to wrap up the stack in a newtype to avoid muddying things up where they're used.

If this isn't your style (and it's not for everyone), you can still use the `mtl` methods to perform operations, while giving an explicit transformer stack. This should cut down on the manual lifting substantially. The advantage of this approach is that it gives you a better view of the interactions of effects at the definition sites; the disadvantage is that more code needs all the information.