# Tidying up Monads - turning application of a monad transformer into newtype monad

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad, newtype, lifting

I am trying to take e.g. `ExceptT a (StateT A M)`, for some concrete type `A` and monad `M`, and wrap them up into my new custom monads.

First I identified that `StateT A M` appears often in other contexts and thus I decided it would be best to wrap that alone in a monad `M1` and then wrap `ExceptT a M1` into `M2`.

The desired property is to make `M1` and `M2` instances of `MonadState` and the class of `M` (lets assume it is called `MyMonadClass`). Also `M2` should be an instance of `MonadError`.

First I started by simple type synonyms:

```
type MyState    = StateT A M
type MyBranch a = ExceptT a MyState
```

then I thought that I would first sketch the instance declarations (without implementing the instance) and thats where I first got stuck. `instance MonadState A (MyState)` seemed to not be the right syntax. I thought I would have to create `newtype MyState' a = StateT a M` and then `type MyState = MyState A` (Lets not use language extensions where not necessary).

However once I started converting the synonyms into `newtype` declarations I started to lose the connection to the `StateT A M` and `ExceptT ...` types.

```
newtype MyState' s a = MyState' { runMyState :: s -> (s, a) }
type MyState = MyState' A
newtype MyBranch e a = MyBranch { runMyBranch :: MyState (Either e a) }
```

Now the transformers that are already implemented disappeared and I think I am trying to do something that does not make much sense. So my question is: How would one correctly wrap this kind of behaviour into new compound monads that make accessible the layers underneath so that one avoids unnecessary lifting and keeps things clear and well-organized.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The normal pattern is to define a newtype for your complete transformer stack.

```
data A = A
data E = E

newtype MyBranchT m a = MyBranchT { getMyBranchT :: ExceptT E (StateT A m) a }
```

If there are any pieces of the stack that add meaningful new capabilities on their own you'd also define newtypes for those pieces.

Then you use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to get instances for all of the various monad classes.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

-- base
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

-- transformers
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy

-- mtl classes
import Control.Monad.Cont.Class
import Control.Monad.Error.Class
import Control.Monad.Reader.Class
import Control.Monad.State.Class
import Control.Monad.Writer.Class

data A = A
data E = E

newtype MyBranchT m a = MyBranchT { getMyBranchT :: ExceptT E (StateT A m) a }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO,     -- classes from base and transformers
              {- Alternative, MonadPlus, -}             -- if E is a monoid
              MonadState A, MonadError E,               -- classes from mtl that MyBranchT provides
              MonadCont, MonadReader r, MonadWriter w)  -- classes from mtl that might be available from m
```

You'll have to write the `MonadTrans` instance by hand. `lift` is always just `lift` once for each of the transformers in the stack.

```
instance MonadTrans MyBranchT where
    lift = MyBranchT . lift . lift
```

If there are any pieces of the stack that add meaningful new capabilities `X` on their own you'd also define a new `MonadX` class for those capabilities, write `MonadX` instances for each of the monad transfomers (`StateT`, `ExceptT`, `ContT`, etc) if possible, and derive the `MonadX` instance for your transformer stack (`MyBranchT`).

You'll also usually make a type synonym for `MyBranchT Identity` and functions to `runMyBranchT` and `runMyBranch`

```
import Data.Functor.Identity

type MyBranch a = MyBranchT Identity a

runMyBranchT :: MyBranchT m a -> A -> m (Either E a, A)
runMyBranchT mb s = runStateT (runExceptT (getMyBranchT mb)) s

runMyBranch :: MyBranch a -> A -> (Either E a, A)
runMyBranch mb s = runIdentity $ runMyBranchT mb s
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a great answer. Can I somehow do without language extensions such as `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`?

Comment: @JakubDaniel Sure, you can write all the instances by hand. But you don't want to (and will probably mess one up), thus `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`.

Comment: To see the actual code that is deriving run the command `:set -ddump-deriv` in GHCi, it shows you all the code GHC generously writes for you. 

`data AB = A | B deriving Eq` dumps `instance GHC.Classes.Eq Ghci5.AB where (GHC.Classes.==) Ghci5.A Ghci5.A = GHC.Types.True; (GHC.Classes.==) Ghci5.B Ghci5.B = GHC.Types.True; (GHC.Classes.==) _ _ = GHC.Types.False`

Comment: @Cirdec I tried to write the instance by hand and failed miserably. Thanks!