# Is there a better way than writing `lift`s before each `IO` in a nested `MonadTrans`?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Sometimes I need to use several nested `MonadTrans`. For example, I would put a `MaybeT` inside of a `ExceptT`, to mimick `continue` and `break` in imperative programming:

```
runExceptT . forM [1..] $ \ _ -> runMaybeT $ do
    ...
    mzero   -- this mimics continue
    lift $ throwE "..."    -- this mimics break
    lift . lift $ putStrLn "Hello!"
    ...
```

However, as the above code shows, every time I need to do any `IO` inside of this "artificial loop", I need to put an ugly `lift . lift` before it. Imagine if I have even more complicated nestings, and a lot of `IO` operations, this quickly becomes an anonyance. How I make the code cleaner and more concise?

Comment: Does using `liftIO` work?

Comment: Note that in some cases it's more efficient to lift things in blocks. `lift $ do {x;y;z}` should be preferred to `do {lift x; lift y; lift z}`. If this turns out to be an issue in a tight loop, you might want `lift $ do {blah; lift bloop}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten monad stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551152/flatten-monad-stack)

Comment: Note that @dfeuer's refactoring is guaranteed to be safe by the monad transformer laws.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the particular case of `IO`, you can use [`liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html) to lift an `IO` action through an arbitrarily deep monad transformer stack:

```
liftIO $ putStrLn "Hello"
```

This expression has type `MonadIO m => m ()`. Any transformer stack that contains an instance of `MonadIO` somewhere inside of it should have a `MonadIO` instance itself, which is why this works for a stack of any depth.